# Row animation and numbering

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me:

1. Add fade animation when adding and deleting rows
2. Why numbers in front of rows are not showing correctly when new row added?

Html:

```
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="8" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="131" scope="col">Roba/Usluga</th>
        <th width="144" scope="col">Jmj</th>
        <th width="144" scope="col">Količina</th>
        <th width="144" scope="col">Jed. cijena</th>
        <th width="144" scope="col">Rabat</th>
        <th width="81" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <select name="sif_roba1" id="sif_roba1">
                <option value="">Please select</option>
                <option value="1">David Hasselhoff</option>
                <option value="2">Michael Jackson</option>
                <option value="3">Tina Turner</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="idjmj1" id="idjmj1">
                <option value="">Please select</option>
                <option value="1">David Hasselhoff</option>
                <option value="2">Michael Jackson</option>
                <option value="3">Tina Turner</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="cijena1" id="cijena1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="track1" id="track1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="rabat1" id="rabat1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="remove_button">Remove</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="add" onClick="clickMe();">Add</button>
```

Js:

```
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        // trigger event when button is clicked
        $("button.add").click(function () {
            // add new row to table using addTableRow function
            addTableRow($("table"));
            // prevent button redirecting to new page
            return false;

        });

        // function to add a new row to a table by cloning the last row and 
        // incrementing the name and id values by 1 to make them unique
        function addTableRow(table) {

            rowCount = 0;
            $("#table tr td:first-child").each(function () {
                rowCount++;
                $(this).text(rowCount);
            });

            // clone the last row in the table
            var $tr = $(table).find("tbody tr:last").clone();


            // get the name attribute for the input and select fields
            $tr.find("input,select").attr("name", function () {
                // break the field name and it's number into two parts
                var parts = this.id.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/);
                // create a unique name for the new field by incrementing
                // the number for the previous field by 1
                return parts[1] + ++parts[2];

                // repeat for id attributes
            }).attr("id", function () {
                var parts = this.id.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/);
                return parts[1] + ++parts[2];
            });
            // append the new row to the table
            $(table).find("tbody tr:last").after($tr);


            // remove rows
            $(".remove_button").live("click", function () {
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();

            })

        };
    });
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/VNBzC/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fade animation is fairly easy.  On the line following where you add the row to the table, add the following code:

```
$tr.hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

For the fade out, you need to remove the row only once the animation is finished, so put it in the animation function's callback:

```
// remove rows
$(".remove_button").live("click", function() {
    $(this).parents("tr").fadeOut('slow', function () { $(this).remove(); } );
});
```

Finally, your count is incorrect because you add the numbers up for the current rows and then clone the last one, so the last number will always be cloned.  To fix this, all you have to do is move your code for adding the row number further down, below the code that clones and adds the rows.  You might also want to add the same code to the fadeOut callback function so that the counts are reset after removing rows.

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VNBzC/6/**

Comment: Thanks, thats it! Only one more thing, when removing a row, variables like input name=+1 stays unchanged, which is not good. Is is possible to change so the variables be the same as row number? For example If the row number is 3, all input boxes variables in that row should also be name=item3.

Comment: Also, rows in your fiddle for some reasone are getting brighter for every time you add one :)

Answer (score 1):

Update for your requirements:

Row Number fix and Add FadeIn

```
 $tr.hide();
 $(table).find("tbody tr:last").after($tr);
 $(table).find("tbody tr:last").find('td:first').html(++rowCount).end().fadeIn(500);
```

Remove FadeOut:

```
 $("table").on("click", ".remove_button", function() {
   $(this).parents("tr").fadeOut(500, function(){ 
      $(this).remove();
 });
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/fppDa/)**

Answer (score 0):

solution to your second problem

**updated js**

```
        $(document).ready(function($)
    {
        // trigger event when button is clicked
        $("button.add").click(function()
        {
            // add new row to table using addTableRow function
            addTableRow($("table"));
            // prevent button redirecting to new page
            return false;

        });

        // function to add a new row to a table by cloning the last row and 
        // incrementing the name and id values by 1 to make them unique
        function addTableRow(table)
        {



            // clone the last row in the table
            var $tr = $(table).find("tbody tr:last").clone();


            // get the name attribute for the input and select fields
            $tr.find("input,select").attr("name", function()
            {
                // break the field name and it's number into two parts
                var parts = this.id.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/);
                // create a unique name for the new field by incrementing
                // the number for the previous field by 1
                return parts[1] + ++parts[2];

            // repeat for id attributes
            }).attr("id", function(){
                var parts = this.id.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/);
                return parts[1] + ++parts[2];
            });
            // append the new row to the table
            $(table).find("tbody tr:last").after($tr);


            // remove rows
            $(".remove_button").live("click", function() {
           $(this).parents("tr").remove();

           })
  rowCount = 0;
    $("#table tr td:first-child").each(function() {
       rowCount++;
      $(this).text(rowCount);   
   });
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Inside the addTableRow() function place this snippet:

```
$("#table tr td:first-child").each(function() {
    rowCount++;
    $(this).text(rowCount);   
});
```

not at the beginning but, at the end of the function body - since you're counting the existing elements here and the new element isn't in place at the beginning of the function yet - it's created later, so the above have to be done at the end.

Answer (score 0):

without changing your code format... for

1) for fade in effect.. you can just use fadeIn() (since fadeIn effect take place only for hidden element.. hide it first and then use fadeIn...

```
$(table).find("tbody tr:last").after($tr).hide().fadeIn();
```

2) and your count is as such because you are counting the `<tr><td>`s count as soon as the add is clicked.. so when appending the text there will be only one field at first... so move the codes to the end and that should do

this

```
rowCount = 0;
$("#table tr td:first-child").each(function() {
    rowCount++;
    console.log(rowCount);
    $(this).text(rowCount);   
});
```

at the end before:

```
$("table").on("click",".remove_button", function() {....
```

**note: `live()` is deprecated and removed in jquery 1.9.... so use `on`**

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VNBzC/7/)